# Handling responded forms in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a simple project that has something like 3 forms and right now I start the component with empty Inputs and then request data from API to pre-populate the form using the `componentWillMount()` hook.

It works for me now but if someday my app need more and more data it would be annoying to do this everytime for any new form and I would like to know if there is any `lib` or `pattern` to help pre-populating forms without using any state container (Redux, mobx, and I really don't know if they are needed in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do your data fetching in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) than in `componentWillMount`:

> If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place
>   to instantiate the network request.

If you want to reuse some data fetching logic without any external state you could use Component with [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) or [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

For example:

```
function withData(fetchData) {
  return BaseComponent => {
    class WithData extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
        }
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        fetchData().then(response => {
          this.setState({ data: response })
        })
      }

      render(){
        return <BaseComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.data} />
      }
    }

    return WithData;
  }
}
```

And later you can reuse this logic:

```
const DataList = ({ data }) => (
  <ul>
    {
      data.map(item => 
        <li>{item.name}</li>
      )
    }
  </ul>
)

// passing Promises as a `data` producers
const UserDataList = withData(fetchUsers)(DataList);
const GroupDataList = withData(fetchGroups)(DataList);
const CatsDataList = withData(() => fetchAnimals('cats'))(DataList);


const ListOfEverything = () => (
  <Container>
    <UserDataList />
    <GroupDataList />
    <CatsDataList />
  </Container>
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomasz this HOC structure will help!